# How to go from Erb to Haml Javascript

Tags: javascript, haml, erb, leaflet

I'm trying to convert my erb file into haml. I figured I could string interpolate most of my code but I'm running into issues when trying to use a JavaScript Leaflet function, L.polygon() (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon), that only accepts numbers. 
Here's my erb code:

```
<h1>MAP!</h1>
<ul>
<li>Start: <%= @start %></li>
<li>End: <%= @end %></li>
</ul>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var map = L.map('map').setView([40.7142, -74.0064], 13);
  L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'Stamen Toner'}, {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map);
  L.marker(<%= @start %>).addTo(map);
  L.marker(<%= @end %>).addTo(map);
  L.polygon([
    <%= @start %>,
    <%= @end %>
]).addTo(map);
</script>
```

And here's my not quite working HAML code:

```
%h1 MAP!
%ul
  %li
    Start: #{@start}
  %li
    End: #{@end}
#map
%script{charset: "utf-8", type: "text/javascript"}
  var map = L.map('map').setView([40.7142, -74.0064], 13);
  L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'Stamen Toner'}, {
  attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);
  L.marker(#{@start}).addTo(map);
  L.marker(#{@end}).addTo(map);
  L.polygon([#{@start},#{@end}]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: How is it not working? You may be better of using the [javascript filter](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter) to avoid Haml trying to parse the js, but in this case I don’t think it should matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try using `parseInt`:

```
L.polygon([parseInt(#{@start}),parseInt(#{@end})]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it didn't appear to work. Here's an example of the rendered HTML
        `L.polygon([parseInt(["40.767272", "-73.993928"]),parseInt(["40.71625", "-74.009105"])]).addTo(map);`

Comment: Can you repost your template code in this comment? It's really strange that it's trying to run `parseInt()` on an `Array` of coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the variables @start and @end are both an array of [latitude, longitude] values as strings from params. I'm using Sinatra and here's my code for the post route `post '/map' do
      @start = params["start"]
      @end = params["end"]
      haml :map
    end`